# ejabberd Fast Reconnect, Push Mode And Last Activity

Tags: ejabberd, xmppframework

We are using ejabberd for our chat client and we are using ProcessOne fast reconnect and push Modules.

We have kept session time to 3 minutes mean after 3 minutes if there is no keep alive packet then server will mark that session expired and user will be treated offline.

If I will query that user last activity then server will returns us timeinterval when user was last online. But during session even my app is terminated then If I query last activity it will returns us user as online.

Question: Does ejabberd returns last activity timer based on session or presence ?

As I can see If I just reconnect with ejabberd and do not send any presence in full authentication not on fast rebind. It treat that user as online.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any XEP that will cover you case. [XEP-0012 Last Activity](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html) is either enabled or not. If enabled, it stores the last activity on the last unavailable presence.

There is several XEP that allow flagging last activity on presence, but they do not offer storage / query ([XEP-0256 - Last Activity in Presence](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0256.html), [XEP-0319 - Last User Interaction in Presence](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0319.html))

It looks like your requirements are not covered by any XEP. You would need a custom protocol (and implementation) of a Last activity based on your exact detailed requirements: What are the criteria for last human activity, how to detect them, do we want to update last activity on disconnect, how to disable the last activity, etc. Nothing exist so something custom need to be designed.

Comment: We have enabled XEP-0012 as mod_last: {} in ejabberd.yml
Our requirements are pretty straight forward that if user A sends his presence unavailable even its session is available and then other user B query about User A last activity then it should return some time as User A presence is unavailable.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. Is that covered by XEP-0012 ? Which section of the spec ? Thing is that mod_last implements XEP-0012. As I understand your original question, it did not seem to match with XEP-0012.

Comment: Well, that's the point of my reply: XEP-0012 does not support that, so you have to design a custom module / protocol. Not sending any presence even in full reconnect does not work because, you cannot do a lot of things with server then (For example, you will not get offline message).

Comment: I do not understand your question. In documentation, it is shown that if you close stream you close your session: "To close the session after p1:push has been enabled send close stream tag: </stream:stream>". It means you are effectively offline. However, if that's your question: "there is no magic stanza to be online and be treated as offline."